# How to catch a property of a JSON object from an Angular HTTP call and fix the "No property" error in Angular CLI?

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am using a public API to fetch movie data. And the following is my service method for getting that data from API:

```
getMovieList(): Observable<Movie[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.moviesURL).pipe(
   map((data: Movie[]) => data),
   catchError(this.handleError),
);
```

}

And this is the method in the component for subscribing that data:

```
getMovieList(): void {
  this.movieApiService.getMovieList()
   .subscribe(
     (data: Movie[]) => {
       this.movieList = data.results;
     }
  );
}
```

The problem is that the API returns an object which has 4 properties: `page`, `results`, `total_pages`, `total_results`. And I only need the `results` property. But when I try to assign `data.results` to my component's property or send `data.results` from my service method instead of `data` then angular cli gives an error of `"results is an undefined property of data"`. My question is how do I get the `results` property directly without having to touch the `data` object and i also need to assign `Movie[]` type to the `results`. But currently I am setting the type to the `data` object.

Comment: Hello @Shuvo  If my answer is correct, can you mark it like that, thanks in advance :D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your model, you defined that you expect array of Movies but you receive the object with 4 properties which one of them called results are the model you defined, so the solution is:

Define the interface like this:

```
  export interface IDataFromApi {
    results: Movie[];
    page: number;
    total_pages: number;
    total_results: number;
}
```

Then the first function will be:

```
  getMovieList(): Observable<IDataFromApi> {
    return this.http.get(this.moviesURL).pipe(
     map((data: IDataFromApi) => data),
     catchError(this.handleError),
  );
```

And method in component:

```
 getMovieList(): void {
  this.movieApiService.getMovieList()
   .subscribe(
     (data: IDataFromApi) => {
       this.movieList = data.results;
     }
  );
}
```

Comment: Hello @Shuvo  If my answer is correct, can you mark it like that, thanks in advance :D .

Comment: Hi Miroslav, your answer is correct but I was waiting for any other suggestions. But nobody seems interested!